# Best db design for elements associated to a default or dynamic category?

Tags: mysql, database-design

So assuming there is a `showrooms` table, a `cars` table, a `trucks` table and a `categories` table (don't mind the naming, you should get the picture). 1 Showroom can have more categories, 1 category can have more cars/trucks associated to it.

My problem is that everything is dynamically added but also, there must be default categories assigned for each showroom (ex. : main category).

Should I generate the default category (ex:showroom_id:1|category:main for categories table) each time a showroom is dynamically added? Or should I make a `default_cars` (no more category association) table and a `custom_cars` (associated to a custom categories) table ? Or any other idea?

Comment: Can categories be shared among showrooms? I.e. is the relationship between showrooms and categories M:N? Also, what's the meaning of "default" category? How do you intend to use it? Is it just a "starting point" that is expected to be modified later or something more permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant consistency of your database tables must be populated in following order:

showroom(1) -> category (2) -> cars/tracks (3)

Your sample is not comprehensive, but let me assume you mean that car should always have correct category. In this case each time when you insert new `showroom` you have attach this default set of categories. Done it in the same transaction. As template for categories you can use either:

- NULL-reference for showroom (showroom_id: **NULL** |category:main )
- Or stand-alone table (template_category)

Comment: Yeah , applyed the null reference in the end (for the main category) , it's better than the stand alone table  . Ty for your answer.